# pyttsx3 не хочет говорить

Tags: python, pyttsx3

есть код, завершается без ошибок, но не выдает то, что должен произнести:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("добрый день сэр")
engine.runAndWait()
```

сообщений об ошибках нет...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй вот такую конфигурацию:

1. Сначала как в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65977155/change-pyttsx3-language) выбираешь себе голос.
2. Адрес запихиваешь вот в этот код:

```
class _TTS:
    engine = None
    rate = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = pyttsx3.init()

    def start(self, text_):
        self.engine.setProperty('voice', 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Speech\\Voices\\Tokens\\TTS_MS_EN-US_ZIRA_11.0') # Вот сюда пихай адрес голоса, в кавычках.
        self.engine.say(text_)
        self.engine.runAndWait()


# и вызываем:

tts = _TTS()
tts.start("добрый день сэр!")
del tts
```

Comment: спасибо, помогли